# @State var not updating View as expected

Tags: swiftui

I have the view below which instantiates a row of buttons, which I intend to make selectable (only one at a time).

```
//@State var currentSelectedIndex = 0
//var rooms: [Room]
    
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false, content: {
            HStack {
                ForEach(rooms.indices) { roomIndex in
                    Button(action: {
                        currentSelectedIndex = roomIndex
                    }) {
                        UserSelectionIcon(room: rooms[roomIndex], selected: roomIndex == currentSelectedIndex)
                            .padding(10)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

When one is selected, it should show a blue circle around it. This is the line in my UserSelectionIcon object referenced above that should do this;

```
//@State var selected: Bool = false

Circle()
     .strokeBorder(selected ? Color.blue.opacity(0.7) : Color.clear, lineWidth: 2)
```

This line does work, as the first index is selected and showing the blue circle. However, clicking any of the buttons does not reveal the blue circle around them. The currentSelectedIndex variable is being updated as expected.

Comment: is your `ForEach`  inside a `List ` or a `ScrollView` ?

Comment: It's in a scrollview

Comment: I edited the post with the full view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `UserSelectionIcon` you have to use `Bindings` to access the `currentSelectedIndex` instead of `States`, as `States` won't update if you change a value in another view.

Therefore you have to safe the `Bool` 'selected' as `Binding` in your `UserSelectionIcon` view. Change this:

```
@State var selected: Bool = false
```

to this:

```
@Binding var selected: Bool
```

and than just refactor this call:

```
UserSelectionIcon(room: rooms[roomIndex], selected: roomIndex == currentSelectedIndex)
```

to this one:

```
UserSelectionIcon(room: rooms[roomIndex], selected: Binding(get: { roomIndex == currentSelectedIndex }, set: {_,_ in }))
```

Now you're wrapping the comparison of the two indices into a binding which will all the time represent the latest comparison of both indices. If you're passing just the comparison then it's like a one-time-value which won't refresh it's result if one of the indices is updated. But now the comparison is reevaluated every time you access the binding when selecting which color should be chosen for the stroke border.

**Alternative Solution:**

You should refactor this:

```
UserSelectionIcon(room: rooms[roomIndex], selected: roomIndex == currentSelectedIndex)
```

to this (to pass the `State` variable):

```
UserSelectionIcon(room: rooms[roomIndex], currentSelectedIndex: currentSelectedIndex)
```

and in your `UserSelectionIcon` you should to refactor this line:

```
@State var selected: Bool = false
```

to:

```
 @Binding var currentSelectedIndex: Bool
```

and every icon should save it's index itself to compare it later:

```
var roomIndex: Int
```

then you can compare these two indices when displaying the border.

```
.strokeBorder(currentSelectedIndex == roomIndex ? Color.blue.opacity(0.7) : Color.clear, lineWidth: 2)
```

Comment: I attempted to use a custom binding because I want to avoid passing the context of the selectedIndex to the child view, as id like it to just be a dumb view with a picture and a circle around it without much else but I failed to do so and have just decided to go with your first solution (which worked of course!!) Thank you

Comment: @JoeyHanlon you're welcome. I will have a look at the custom binding, maybe I can implement a working solution

Comment: the binding felt weird to me, as I do not really need the "set" part of it in this case

Comment: @JoeyHanlon you're right, you basically don't need the 'set' part of the binding. I updated my answer to illustrate how it's working